# c# Invalid operation in several threads:Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to change position of my coursor but it returns error. Please help me change my code. I read about Invoke but I don't know how to use as I am a beginner to c#.
Thank you!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( DisplayTimeEvent );
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Start();              
        }

       public  void DisplayTimeEvent( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
       {
            MoveCursor();
       }

       private void MoveCursor()
       {
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 10, Cursor.Position.Y - 10);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use multi-threading as a beginner. In this case this means using a WinForms timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) instead of `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: You may use the search function, you know? This question has been answered so often here on SO I stopped counting...

Answer (score 1):

This is a server timer which fires its timer events away from the UI thread. Which causes the problem you observe because you must interact with UI on the main UI thread.

You need a UI timer which will fire its timer events on the main UI thread. For instance: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: That being said: You *can* use the `System.Timers.Timer` in GUI applications, too, you just have to make sure to access the GUI from the GUI thread only.

Comment: Yes you can Invoke to the main thread but that's *n extra complication that is nice to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

In WPF it is :

A) change your timer to : DispatcherTimer - with this Timer you can change in the tick event gui elements

B)
Call your "MoveMouse" in the GUI Thread

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    MoveMouse();
                }));
```

Heres a useful link FOR WINFORMS:
http://blog.altair-iv.com/2013/02/ui-access-from-background-thread-in.html

Comment: `namespace WindowsFormsApplication8` suggests that this may not be WPF

Comment: Isn't it easier just to use the WinForms timer?

Comment: I think so, but the WinFormsTimer was answered before ;) so i googled an other way..

Answer (score -2):

for your case you may try this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5000 is 5 seconds. i.e. after 5 seconds i am changing the cursor position. 
        MoveCursor();
    }

    private void MoveCursor()
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 10, Cursor.Position.Y - 10);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: 1) How does that address the question? 2) Why sleep for 5 seconds?

Comment: 1)the Question was just to change the location of Pointer, the code does that, 2)Sleep for 5 seconds because the Questioner wants the same.(any how that's just a pause to visualize the change in position) @CodesInChaos